# jQuery How to get a variable inside a button id tag inside .html function

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a jquery line of code that outputs some HTML to a div. Thing is, that HTML has some button tags which need an ID containing a javascript variable called postID.

```
$('#Message_' + postID).css('visibility','visible').html('').html('I need the buttons to have an ID with the postID variable!<br /><button type="button" id="remindMe_" + postID">Remind Me</button><button type="button" id="cancelMe" + postID">Cancel</button>').prependTo('#buttons_' + postID);
```

So the question is, how do I fix

```
.html('<button type="button" id="remindMe_" + postID">Remind Me</button>')
```

Comment: Why would anyone down rate this? This is a legitimate question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
.html('<button type="button" id="remindMe_' + postID + '">Remind Me</button>')
```

That is, using exactly the same technique that you already used in this part:

```
$('#Message_' + postID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `'` before + and `+ '` after postID???

And this is a really really basic JS question. I suggest you to read a JavaScript beginnersguide before...

---

```
.html().html('Some text')
```

The first `.html()` in this snippet won't make any difference in how it renders, but the speed will be faster if you remove this.

Comment: I realize it is a basic question. I have tried many combinations of quotation marks and none did the trick. It is the + '" part that I had overlooked.